# Change timezone with Carbon

Tags: laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I have a date that is coming from database (type date):

```
2018-08-25
```

This date is in french timezone.

When I do:

```
    $from = Carbon::parse("2018-08-25", 'Europe/Paris');
    $from->timezone('UTC');
    dd($from);
```

I get:

```
  date: 2018-08-24 22:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
```

Which is what I want

But when I use field from DB:

```
    $operation = Operation::findOrFail($request->operation);
    $from = Carbon::parse($operation->date_ini, 'Europe/Paris');
    $from->timezone('UTC');
    dd($from);
```

I get:

```
date: 2018-08-25 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
```

In my DB, field is saved as : `2018-08-25`, so literraly, it means `2018-08-25 UTC`. So result is coherent. But I'm not sure how to deal with it to get what I want. The implication would be that I have to store my date like a datetime in DB so that I can store it in UTC with 1 or 2 hours less. Is there anyway to avoid this and keep it simple ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

If you call setTimezone() on an existing instance of Carbon, it will change the date/time to the new timezone, for example

```
$changeTimeZone =  \Carbon\Carbon::parse($operation->date_ini)->setTimezone('Asia/Dhaka')->format('H:i');
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using:

```
$from = Carbon::parse($operation->date_ini)->shiftTimezone('Europe/Paris');;
```

`shiftTimezone` with change timezone without changing the date. So, it do the trick for me !